# Spring Cache Update

Tags: java, spring, caching

Is it possible to have Spring's caching abstraction *populate* the cache with a given item, rather than just have it read-through?

Imagine I have the methods `Thing getItem(UUID id)` and `setItem(UUID id, Thing thing)`. I'd like to use `@Cacheable` on the former to have it read from the cache, and if it is absent invoke the underlying method. When the setter is called, I'd like the parameter `thing` to be added to the cache and then have the method invoked, persisting it to underlying storage.

Comment: I was answering your question with "CachePut", but looking at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-put you would have to return "thing" for it to work. I guess that a better answer would be to annotate setItem with "CacheEvict" so it deletes the old value from the cache. The next time getItem is called, it will be populated with the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Luciano stated you could set @CachePut annotation on the method, but as he states it will cause you to modify your API. That might be an advantage though, depending on whether or not you like the semantics you receive with the fluid API style.

You have another option though, but it will tie you to Spring, and cause your setItem code to be a bit nastier.  You could always wire in the CacheManager and set the data on the cache in itself in the setItem method.

So it'd look something like this:

```
@Autowire private CacheManager cacheManager;

public void setItem(UUID id, Thing thing) {
  Cache c = cacheManager.getCache("cacheName");
  if (c != null) {
    c.put(id, thing);   
  }
  //Do more
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is capable of doing this. It just lets you to define instances to be cached via `@Cachable` and removing them via `@CacheEvict`. As I know there is no other way to interfere with this working mechanism.
Also you can define a custom annotation to achieve same functionality.